# Can not Deploy ERC20 Token using Truffle

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc20

I'd like to deploy follow "StandardERC20" token to kovan test net using Truffle.
I want to deploy same contract like
"https://etherscan.io/address/0x69d9905b2e5f6f5433212b7f3c954433f23c1572#code" to kovan.
But I got follow errors.
I added error log and some files needed to deploy this token.
And I found that error is in "ServiceReceiver(receiver).pay{value: msg.value}(serviceName);" of ServicePayer.sol.
last address parameter of deploy function in  2_deploy_token.js is my wallet address. is it correct?
And I tried to use remix. But I couldn't deploy it.
What Can I do for this error?
Help me,everyone!
-Error log-

```
D:\work\Project\alone\monkey-coin>npx truffle migrate --network kovan

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\ServicePayer.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\ServiceReceiver.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\TokenRecover.sol
> Artifacts written to D:\work\ph\Project\alone\monkey-coin\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.7.0+commit.9e61f92b.Emscripten.clang



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'kovan'
> Network id:      42
> Block gas limit: 12500000 (0xbebc20)


2_deploy_token.js
=================

   Deploying 'StandardERC20'
   -------------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x3628fb04e7566dd9619e790e3e0f0dc4aa31c4c59c31a4acdcddadeae11418ac

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"StandardERC20" -- Cannot create instance of StandardERC20; no code at address 0x210f50C6ED1251606Cb8EfE2D191788d141bF935.
```

-migaration/2_deploy_token.js

```
const StandardERC20 = artifacts.require("StandardERC20");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(StandardERC20, 'Happy Bear', 'HBT', 18, 1000000000, '0x4d1c919d233E5c35a9A5a12e82f7D5b12D071997');
};
```

-contracts/ServiceReceiver.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

//import "eth-token-recover/contracts/TokenRecover.sol";
import "./TokenRecover.sol";
/**
 * @title ServiceReceiver
 * @dev Implementation of the ServiceReceiver
 */
contract ServiceReceiver is TokenRecover {

    mapping (bytes32 => uint256) private _prices;

    event Created(string serviceName, address indexed serviceAddress);

    function pay(string memory serviceName) public payable {
        require(msg.value == _prices[_toBytes32(serviceName)], "ServiceReceiver: incorrect price");

        emit Created(serviceName, _msgSender());
    }

    function getPrice(string memory serviceName) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _prices[_toBytes32(serviceName)];
    }

    function setPrice(string memory serviceName, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _prices[_toBytes32(serviceName)] = amount;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(amount);
    }

    function _toBytes32(string memory serviceName) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(serviceName));
    }
}
```

-contracts/ServicePayer.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "./ServiceReceiver.sol";

/**
 * @title ServicePayer
 * @dev Implementation of the ServicePayer
 */
contract ServicePayer {

    constructor (address payable receiver, string memory serviceName) payable {
        ServiceReceiver(receiver).pay{value: msg.value}(serviceName);
    }
}
```

-contracts/TokenRecover.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

/**
 * @title TokenRecover
 * @author Vittorio Minacori (https://github.com/vittominacori)
 * @dev Allow to recover any ERC20 sent into the contract for error
 */
contract TokenRecover is Ownable {

    /**
     * @dev Remember that only owner can call so be careful when use on contracts generated from other contracts.
     * @param tokenAddress The token contract address
     * @param tokenAmount Number of tokens to be sent
     */
    function recoverERC20(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokenAmount) public onlyOwner {
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(owner(), tokenAmount);
    }
}
```

-contracts/StandardERC20.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "./ServicePayer.sol";
/**
 * @title StandardERC20
 * @dev Implementation of the StandardERC20
 */
contract StandardERC20 is ERC20, ServicePayer {

    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint8 decimals,
        uint256 initialBalance,
        address payable feeReceiver
    ) ERC20(name, symbol) ServicePayer(feeReceiver, "StandardERC20") payable {
        require(initialBalance > 0, "StandardERC20: supply cannot be zero");

        _setupDecimals(decimals);

        _mint(_msgSender(), initialBalance);
    }
}
```

-package.json

```
{
  "name": "monkey-coin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.3.0-solc-0.7",
    "truffle": "^5.1.60"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

I want to deploy this token surely.
Help Me!!!

Comment: What is in your  `migrations/` directory

Comment: 1_initial_migration.js, 2_deploy_token.js

Comment: const StandardERC20 = artifacts.require("./StandardERC20.sol");
//const ServicePayer = artifacts.require("./ServicePayer.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
 deployer.deploy(StandardERC20, 'Happy Bear', 'HBT', '0x48a0806dC7C143F4e31A68dd5590CB57b1b89cda');
//  deployer.deploy(ServicePayer, '0x48a0806dC7C143F4e31A68dd5590CB57b1b89cda', 'StandardERC20');
};

Comment: Cant really see the code above properly. Can u try updating the code above into the question with proper formatting?

Comment: sorry. I updated question. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, Ming! I'm really sorry for you. Could you tell me your mail address?